# IDAPython: error executing init.py:

Tags: ida, idapython

When I open Ida Pro 7.3 I see an error message

```
IDAPython: error executing init.py:
nothing to repeat

Refer to the message window to see the full error log.
```

How can I understand what is the problem? in message windows I not see any problem.

I have python in PATH .and only 1 installation of python

Comment: Have u found the answer yet ?

Comment: Can you provide the `init.py`? Does this error come from any extension?

Comment: If it is the `init.py` in `[IDA_DIRECTORY]/python/[2 or 3]/init.py`, then maybe your IDA installation is broken

Answer (score 0):

Read READMY_python3.txt in the folder where IDA is installed.
For example, in my case on Windows, running idapyswitch.exe and selecting one of the installed Python distributions helped.